# JavaScript - Show a div without using display:none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a div that I want to be "activated" on a click but **only the first time, only when it doesn't exist yet** ; I don't want to use `display:none` by default because when coming back to the page afterwards I would have to click again to make it appear.

To sum up, is there any way to "activate" a div instead of using show/hide? (`createElement` and `append` would make a new one on each click...)

Comment: If I understand right, you want the state to persist between refresh ?

Comment: Yes exactly. If the display was "none" initially, then it would be set to "block" for example, and remain "block" even after refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`appendTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) for that. If you give that `div` an unique ID, you can check if it exists

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if( $('#uniqueID').length == 0 ) {
    $('<div id="uniqueID">This is a div</div>').appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add div</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that's what I was looking for yes ! The thing is, the div I want to append is in a TWIG and there are variables and conditions check in the middle, I don't know if it's related but it doesn't seem to make anything happen when I click

Comment: You might need to append it to different element. This code adds it to (the end  of) the body. You also might need to add some CSS styling to it to make it fit to your page.

Comment: It works with text on the right click and it gets appended to the right spot so thank you for that ; but I can't seem to append a button with its "href" being 
`<a href="{{ path('vote_delete',{'slug' : slug, 'proposal' : proposal.id, 'vote' : vote.id}) }}" class="btn btn-light ml-1 btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i> {{ 'vote-delete' | trans }}</a>`
Mainly, I think, because these variables are set in a loop in the TWIG...

Comment: Okay it's working it's just that TWIG curly braces {{ break the script... But I need them, is there any way to use them in a script?